# What actually executes instructions of a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I'm a newbie to virtualization and tried to delve deep.I get this doubt whether it is the hypervisor which actually executes the instructions provided by the guest OS in a VM(Virtual machine) or do the instructions go straight away to the actual processor?Or maybe the instructions pass through the hypervisor and then go to the actual CPU.

I've formed this opinion that the instructions ultimately will be processed by the actual CPU basing it on the idea that if a VM tried to process instructions on its own version of the virtualized CPU it must allocate all the allowed CPU resource at once which isn't actually happening.But I don't seem to get a solid resource to prove it.All I get to know is that the hypervisor is a software layer which manages resources for guest OS from host.Moreover, do the instructions go through the hypervisor(like a C++ code goes through compiler) if executed by the actual CPU?
Also is it a possibility that the hypervisor converts the guest instructions into assembly language that the actual processor understands?

Comment: It depends. Assume your vm and your host are of the same arch, and you use hardware-assisted virtualization (e.g. Intel VMX). Most instructions will be executed directly by CPU, but some privileged instructions like accessing hardware will be trapped to hypervisor, and the hypervisor handles them.

Comment: Makes sense.But can you please elaborate "hypervisor handles them" of the last line?

Comment: For example, on x86 platform, you set a different cpu model for your vm. Then if you execute CPUID instruction in your vm, it will be trapped to hypervisor (it is also called vm exit), the hypervisor emulates the instruction (here it is write the virtual cpu model to the saved vm registers), then return to vm (this is called vm entry). @Vardin